# Android: Is it possible to set multiple fragment factories? "Unable to instantiate Fragment xxx"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, androidx, dagger-hilt

I am trying to set multiple `fragment factories` to my `MainNavHostFragment`. My problem is that my approach doesn't work and it only accepts the last set fragmentFactory.

I tried to google it but there is not a single page that says / not says that we could create multiple `FragmentFactories`... I want multiple fragmentfactories to achieve better readability

### Current Approach

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainNavHostFragment : NavHostFragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var mainFragmentFactory: MainFragmentFactory
    @Inject lateinit var emailFragmentFactory: EmailFragmentFactory
    @Inject lateinit var shopFragmentFactory: ShopFragmentFactory
    @Inject lateinit var userLogInProcessFragmentFactory: UserLogInProcessFragmentFactory
    @Inject lateinit var userRegistrationFragmentFactory: UserRegistrationFragmentFactory
    @Inject lateinit var userDataFragmentFactory: UserDataFragmentFactory

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = mainFragmentFactory
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = emailFragmentFactory
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = shopFragmentFactory
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = userLogInProcessFragmentFactory
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = userRegistrationFragmentFactory
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = userDataFragmentFactory
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found anything as of yet?

Comment: @Urmzd No, I don't think this is possible..